# Ionic 2 Facebook comments widgets facebook comment view is not showing

Tags: cordova, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, angular2-directives

I am using facebook comment plugin in my ionic app and using below code snippet  in index.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src =   "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId='My_fbApp_Id'";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And last HTML code to show comment box.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="true" data-width="100%" page-href="https://facebook.com/" data-numposts="15"></div>
```

This working fine with chrome but when I build APK file and try to run app comment box invisible within a second please   solve my issue

Comment: I get the solution when i add                                              
  .fb_hide_iframes iframe{
        left:0px !important;
        
    }   line in my home.css file problem solved and comment box visible

Comment: this worked but it is not showing previous comments  even though the url is correct and if it is showing the comment section only for the first time